# Show nodes contaning same company term in Views

Tags: views, 8

I need to show a block on a node page which will show all nodes containing same company name taxonomy term.

What is the way to do it? I've tried adding a field_company term relationship but it's not working.

A product whose company term contains Samsung so when this product(node) is viewed I want to display other products from same company Samsung.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new block view either selecting the single content type or all. Now, we will add two contextual filters. Content Id and the field which has taxonomy term id.

Configure Content Id filter as follows:

1. Provide default value: Content ID from URL
2. Under More tab - Check next to Exclude

Configure field which has taxonomy term id as follows:

1. Provide default value: Taxonomy term ID from URL
2. Uncheck: Load default filter from term page
3. Check next to Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy block
4. Multiple value handling: Filter items that share any value.
5. Under more tab check: Allow multiple values.

That's it. After saving your view go to bock page and enable it where ever you want.

Comment: To note, the contextual filters preview won't work with this but when dropped into a page it works beautifully